# Headers on CSS Columns

Tags: html, css

I have a document that is displayed using CSS columns, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcwzpra/).  The contents of the jsFiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="two-column"> [some sample content] </div>
```

CSS:

```
.two-column {
    width: 610px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Obviously, this will only work for webkit browsers, remove/replace the prefix for other engines.

I wish to add a header to every column, but haven't found any documentation that seems relevant (searches are filled with hits for CSS and table columns, or visual "columns" as in 2- or 3-column page layout).

I can position things absolutely for every column with javascript, but I'm hoping that a cleaner, CSS solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/ydcwzpra/1/

```
<div class="two-column2">
    <h1>asd1</h1>
    <h1>asd2</h1>
</div>
<div class="two-column">

    The div.two-column element will be broken up into two columns via the column-width CSS rule. Notice how the image that is too large to fit fully on this column is pushed to the next.

    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250/" />

    Here is some more text.

</div>
```

```
.two-column {
    width: 610px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
.two-column2, .two-column2 > h1 {
    width: 610px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-column-width: 300px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

It is not perfect code, but hope you've got the idea.

Comment: While using columns to position the headers sounds like a good idea, this looks like I'll have to know the number of columns before hand, or calculate them with javascript after the content has been laid out.

Comment: @bdares, I can suggest you to use flex-box instead of block divs. It is very powerful tool: chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/using-flexbox-today